# Which is stronger condition, $R$-algebra hom or $R$-mod hom?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Which is stronger condition, $R$-algebra hom and $R$-mod hom?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. $R$-algebra is always can be regarded as $R$-module.But what about morphism ?
$R$-algebra homomorphism $f$ is always $R$-mod homomorphism?

Comment: What does the definition of $R$-algebra homomorphism say?

Comment: Every $R$-algebra morphism is an $R$-module morphism, but not conversely. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-modules (i.e. rational vector spaces), but not as $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras.